How to treat juxtaposition between vector and column and how to handle them?
In his article word2vec Parameter Learning Explained Xin Rong uses a juxtaposition of two vectors (a row and a column) to compute the resulting value:
$$ u_j = v_{w_j}^T h  \tag 2$$
where both operands are columns.
How this juxtaposition should be treated in this case?
In the Product between a column vector and a row vector they say that the result is matrix since these vectors must be treated as matrices. At the same time in the article, the result us used as scores like he just calculated the dot product between these two vectors.
In absence of the operation between these two, how should be treated?
I will be thankful for textbook reference, as well, so that I could revisit this.

If $s,t \in F^n$ are column vectors; i.e., we can write $$ s = \begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ \vdots \\ s_n
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } t = \begin{pmatrix} t_1 \\ \vdots \\ t_n
\end{pmatrix},$$
then they are essentially elements of $\mathbb{M}_{n \times 1}(F)$. As you know, matrix multiplication works by element-wise multiplying a row in the first matrix times a column in the second, so we cannot meaningfully multiply $st$. One way around this, is to take the transpose of either $s$ or $t$. If we do the former, then $$s^Tt = \begin{pmatrix}s_1 & \cdots & s_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} t_1 \\ \vdots \\ t_n
\end{pmatrix} = s \cdot t \in F \cong \mathbb{M}_{1 \times 1}(F),$$ the dot product (returns a scalar). If we do the latter, then $$ st^T = \begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ \vdots \\ s_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}t_1 & \cdots & t_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}s_1 t_1 & \cdots & s_1 t_n \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ s_n t_1 & \cdots & s_n t_n \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{M}_{n \times n}(F),$$ a matrix.
Our dimensions of the product depend on which vector takes the transpose, entirely because of how we defined matrix multiplication.
Since the order of your example has $v_{w_j}^T h$, transpose first, the result will be equal to $v_{w_j} \cdot h$, the dot product.
